Reset bash password wsl (powershell, w11)
I installed Bash in PowerShell a few weeks ago, but I had an issue creating the password. The one I tried doesn't work, so I'd like to reset it. I've tried various tutorials online, but none of the recommended commands worked.
Here's what I've tried: https://askubuntu.com/questions/772050/reset-the-password-in-ubuntu-linux-bash-in-windows

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Ubuntu version matters for the command used, or [user] default can be edited in the wsl.conf

@JW0914 Thank you! How can I find out which Ubuntu version is installed?

I solved the issue, thank you very much!

If you shared with us how you solve your problem, posting it as an answer down in the appropriate section, that would help others out having the same problem, and earn you some site reputation too.
